# Excel VBA For Loop writing Formula in cells depending on the number in the loop

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, concatenation, formula

I am trying to write a Forumla in cells (from cell A2 to AI, where I is the number in the For Loop).
The formula to be written must correspond to Cell M2 to MI, also where I is the number in the For Loop.

I am able to write the sheet-reference by itself:

```
ws.Cells(1 + I, KolonneForX + 1).Formula = " ='" & ws.Name & "'"
```

which gives me the formula  `='Ark1'` (by it self) in the cells i want.

And also the right name of cell to read:

```
ws.Cells(1 + I, KolonneForX + 2).Formula = "=CONCATENATE(""M"",TEXT(" & I & "+1,""0""))"
```

which gives me the formula  `MI` (by it self, with the corresponing number for I) in the cells i want.

But when I try to put the two of them togheter, I can't get it to run and refer to the right cells.

This is the code I have been trying to run:

```
Sub OppretteKnutepunkt()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Ark1")
    Dim KolonneForX As Integer

    For I = 1 To 5
        ws.Cells(1 + I, KolonneForX + 2).Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!CONCATENATE(""M"",TEXT(" & I & "+1,""0""))"
    Next I
End Sub
```

I want the Cell `A2` to have the following formula:

```
='Ark1'!M2
```

I want the Cell `A3` to have the following formula:

```
='Ark1'!M3
```

and so on.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this without looping

```
Dim I as Long    
I = 7
With ws.Range("A2:A" & I)
    .Formula = "='" & .Parent.Name & "'!M2"
End With
```

`With` is a shorthand way of using the same prefix on a block of code. The `VBA` compiler prefixes everything that begins with a `.` with whatever is declared by the `With` block

The equivalent of the above would be:

```
ws.Range("A2:A" & I).Formula = "='" & ws.Range("A2:A" & I).Parent.Name & "'!M2"
```

Comment: This work great for A2 to A7.
I am not so familiar with "With" though. 
Is it possible to make it to do it on range "A2:AI", Where I is a vaiable?

Comment: A `With` block is basically a shorthand way of writing the same bit of syntax. i.e. Everything with just a dot (`.`) infront of it the VBA compiler prefixes whatever is declared by the `With` block. Have updated to use a variable for the last row of the range

Comment: Thank you very much @Tom, for taking time to help and explain. 
This works Perfect!